# HTML - Use Microsoft Access VBA to click on a certain tab on a website through IE

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

Here's what the tabs on the website look like:
[image: tabs]

When they are clicked it activates a different table of data underneath.

I am trying to activate the RIGS tab. Here is what the HTML code for all of the tabs included in the picture:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs di-nav-tabs" ng-class="{'show-scroll': tabsNeedScroll}">
  <!-- ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><li ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active, disabled: tab.disabled}" ng-if="isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId)" class="ng-scope">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(tab)" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- ngIf: tab.group==='International' -->
      Leases
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><li ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active, disabled: tab.disabled}" ng-if="isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId)" class="ng-scope active" style="">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(tab)" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- ngIf: tab.group==='International' -->
      Production
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><li ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active, disabled: tab.disabled}" ng-if="isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId)" class="ng-scope">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(tab)" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- ngIf: tab.group==='International' -->
      Wells
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><li ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active, disabled: tab.disabled}" ng-if="isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId)" class="ng-scope">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(tab)" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- ngIf: tab.group==='International' -->
      Permits
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><li ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active, disabled: tab.disabled}" ng-if="isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId)" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(tab)" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- ngIf: tab.group==='International' -->
      Rigs
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><li ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active, disabled: tab.disabled}" ng-if="isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId)" class="ng-scope">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(tab)" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- ngIf: tab.group==='International' -->
      Landtrac Lease
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><li ng-repeat="tab in tabState.tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active, disabled: tab.disabled}" ng-if="isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId)" class="ng-scope">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(tab)" class="ng-binding">
      <!-- ngIf: tab.group==='International' -->
      Landtrac Unit
    </a>
  </li><!-- end ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs --><!-- ngIf: isDatasourceVisible(tab.datasourceId) --><!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabState.tabs -->

  <li ng-class="{active: shapefileTableInfo.active, disabled: shapefileTableInfo.disabled}" ng-show="hasShapefiles()" class="" style="">
    <a href="" ng-click="select(shapefileTableInfo)">Shapefiles</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried a number of methods to activate the RIGS tab and none have done the trick. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "I have tried a number of methods" - usually best to show what code you tried, and describe what happened when you ran it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. I agree it is best practice, but I have been just adding and stepping through to test, when it doesn't work, I move on and try something else. I will track down some examples of what I have tried. I was hoping there was an obvious solution since I don't know too much about HTML.  Again thanks for the reply

Comment: Something like `doc.getElementsByTagName("a").getElementsByClassName("ng-binding")`  to get all of the tabs and then loop over that collection to find an element whose `innerText` contains "Rigs"

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make out the syntax.  Does it read 'Production'?

```
Sub DownloadData()

Dim lColumn As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rwsToCheck As Long
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")


With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "your_url_here"

' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop


For Each Anchor In ieAnchors 
    If Anchor.innerHTML Like "*Production*" Then 
        Anchor.Click 
        Exit For 
    End If 
Next Anchor 


End Sub
```